# Linux - set tmpfs ram size rather than overall size

Tags: linux, memory, tmpfs

I have the following setup on my server:

16G RAM
64G swap

I want to setup a tmpfs partition with the following options:

- use up to 50% RAM (8G)
- have the total size of tmpfs 8G + swap size = 72G

In other words, I want the first 8G of data in tmpfs go to memory, and anything above that to be written to disk.

Is this possible?

The options I found in tmpfs docs and fstab examples only allowed me to limit the total size of the filesystem. So if I set it to a large number, it may eat up all my available ram. If I set it to a smaller number, it won't eat up the ram, but there may not be enough space for the application needs.

thanks!

Comment: You can't control this. You can only choose a total size.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish here? There's likely a more functional way to go about it.

Comment: thanks @MichaelHampton, if you post this as an answer I will accept it.